# Postgis allows to add invalid geometry

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a table `layer` with a geometry column `geom`. This geometry column has such constraints:

```
 CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_geom CHECK (st_ndims(geom) = 2),
 CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom CHECK (geometrytype(geom) = 'POLYGON'::text),
 CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_geom CHECK (st_srid(geom) = 3857)
```

So, as you can see, there is nothing special about this geometry column. But what is interesting, is that it allows me to add incorrect geometry to the table:

```
insert into layer (geom) values (
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((4831087.7172221 7576170.7140277,
      4829023.9174584 7556144.212617, 
      4834450.9464667 7556602.8347867, 
      4833533.7021273 7575329.9067165, 
      4831087.7172221 7576170.7140277),
     (4815647.4375453 7566616.0854925, 
      4817864.1113651 7574183.3512927, 
      4825049.1920219 7573342.5439816, 
      4821609.5257499 7567609.7668602, 
      4815647.4375453 7566616.0854925))', 3857)
);
```

The thing is this is not a polygon with a "hole". These are two different polygons which stay apart. Why is that? Why does Postgis allow to add incorrect geometry?

**EDIT**

I checked this geometry with `ST_IsValid` and it is false. So, it all looks like a bug in Postgis.

Comment: This is by design, and not a bug. Invalid geometries exist and must be stored somehow and ideally fixed. If you don't want them in a table, add a check constraint (as I see you have done in a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a polygon from any closed line, like

```
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 0, 1 1, 0 0))')
```

even though that does not make a valid polygon.

Use a check constraint with the `st_isvalid()` function!

Comment: Thanks! One tiny question: how this constraint should look like in a table schema? Something like `CONSTRAINT enforce_valid_geom CHECK (st_isvalid(geom))` ?